# Caching in WSO2 Data Services Server 3.5.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

¿Is there any way to enable caching in WSO2 DSS 3.5.0? In previous versions I could activate it from Quality of Service Panel, but it has disappeared in the new versions.

I can't figure out the way to do this in the WSO2 Developer Studio, there is no cache policy template or caching options.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you try this?

https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS310/Response+Caching

Comment: The Quality is Service Panel has disappeared in 3.5.0 version. I have tried to enable caching by creating a separate configuration file (MyService_services.xml) and placed it in the data services deployment directory, commented out the line in axis2.xml and restarted the server, but it didn't worked.

Comment: same didn't work for me as well